# Facebook in-app browser problem with links containing target="_blank"

Tags: facebook, inappbrowser

We have a price comparison website that uses a lot of out of site links with target="_blank". In Facebook in-app browser those links are not working from 31.1.2019. I notices that this is not working on many sites, even clicks on banners are not working.
Is this some bug or what could be wrong ?  This is a major problem because we are spending a lot of money for advertising on FB but now links are not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was due to this bug: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=927254#c31

Unfortunately, though this was "fixed" yesterday, users will continue to experience the problem until their side has been updated. https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=927254#c35

It's amazing that Facebook was made aware of this problem and nothing has been done during the past 7 days.

Facebook mobile's browser is widely used these days so this might be a more serious problem than people think. Ads were being loaded in the background when clicked from what I can understand. Advertisers are not gonna be happy.

Comment: Thank you for the answer

Comment: Do we have any update on that issue?
I am still experiencing it on Android device on my websites that cannot open external links!
I am trying on Chrome 73.